# Eclipse Galileo does not deploy external jars into WEB-INF/lib directory

Tags: eclipse, galileo, eclipse-3.5

I created new web project testweb.

By default default output folder is **testweb\build\classes**.

Added some jars to build path.

Then selected these jars in "Java EE Module Dependencies" in order to Eclipse put this jars into WEB-INF/lib during deploying on some server.

Then I deployed this web application from Eclipse on server(JBoss).

All is ok - there are jars in WEB-INF/lib directory.

But if I change default output folder from **testweb\build\classes** to **testweb\web\WEB-INF\classes** Eclipse stops to deploy external jars to WEB-INF/lib directory.

This directory is empty!
Why?
What is wrong?

Comment: Does the workaround mentioned in this old bug report (i.e. "don't use WEB-INF/classes") work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [bug 266268](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=266268) , also described in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg17851.html).
Notes:

- this was for eclipse3.4, do you still have this issue with the latest eclipse3.5.1 (since "Galileo" could be just 3.5)?
- there is a [debug procedure](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg18256.html).

> Thanks to Larry and his hints for debugging I found the source cause of this:
>   don't use `WEB-INF/classes` as the default output folder. There is a bug (probably), that makes eclipse to calculate project contents differently in this case.
>
> So the workaround solution is to change the default output folder.

The bug is a duplicate of [bug 249044](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=249044), reported fixed in WTP3.0.5: what version of WTP do you have with your Galileo eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse Web Developer Tools
Version: 3.1.0.v200905242131-7R77FShEVw2xUGpF1LiNxdVAELXy
Build id: 20090616035105